# The Prison Escape Pt. 1 (THE DOOR)

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, story, computer-puzzle

**You are currently escaping a prison owned by a mad scientist.**

> As you were about to approach a large iron door that you think should be
>   leading to the exit, a guard came out from the shadows.
>
> You quickly hid behind some wooden crates, next to your wife and
>   daughter, who were anxiously waiting for you.
>
> You silently watch from your hiding place.
>
> **You see the guard flip some levers. There were four.** Two levers were flipped while the guard was reading on some kind of PDA. The
>   guard then pressed a big red button next to the levers. Two seconds pass by, then you hear the door slide up with a loud screeching noise.
>
> The moment the guard walked through that door, it immediately slammed
>   shut, with a big thud.
>
> You note the lever positions: **Down Up Down Down**
>
> As you were hoping that the guard forgot to reset the password, you
>   see an anxious person run towards the door. He presses the button,
>   nothing happens. You can see the despair on his face as he presses the
>   button a second time, he then erratically flips three of the levers.
>   As he pressed the red button for a third time, two guards came out of
>   the shadows and dragged him away. You feel as if you are going to be the next one
>   to end up like him.
>
> You wait until nighttime. (At least you think it is nighttime, there
>   is neither sunlight nor clocks to keep track of time.)
>
> This time you approach the door, you look around. There is no one.
>
> Before touching anything, you note the new lever positions: **Up Down
>   Down Up**
>
> You open the panel that houses the door controls, everything is neatly
>   packed, and you see no wires, but you do see one integrated circuit.
>   You remember that you still have your C-SCAN 3000, a device that can
>   scan a microprocessor and return its internal memory state.
>
> To your surprise, it worked! You eagerly tear out the printed
>   piece of paper.

```
-----------------
|   -0004502-   |
|MICP @4cyc/s   |
|ARCH: UNK      |
|MEM:  4-bit    |
|INST: 3-bit    |
|               |
|BEGIN BIN DUMP |
|***************|
|0000   001 1111|
|0001   010 1101|
|0010   001 1101|
|0011   001 1100|
|0100   101 0111|
|0101   010 1101|
|0110   000 0000|
|0111   010 1101|
|1000   111 0000|
|1001   000 0000|
|1010   000 0000|
|1011   000 0000|
|1100   000 1101|
|1101   000 1110|
|1110   000 0000|
|1111   000 0110|
|***************|
|ACC &%#$  ERROR|
|ENCRYPTED VALUE|
|               |
|1111 EXT.      |
|               |
|FURTHER DEBUG. |
|UPGRADE TO C-  |
|SCAN 4000+     |
|               |
|EOF            |
-----------------
```

**What are the next lever positions that will allow you to open the door?**

*Bonus: As the door only opens for one person, find out the three next lever positions, so everyone in your family can escape.*

This might be a very hard puzzle, but I will give out hints and clear out any confusions as needed.

**Ok it's been 3 months, I think I can give out acceptable hints:**

- Decoding the instructions shouldn't be hard, what are the basic instructions for a Turing-complete computer? (The **absolute basic** to be able to make any **meaningful and useful** program)
- There are only 5 instructions used, so it narrows down a lot of the possibilities
- Be careful, the computer runs at 4Hz, but doesn't mean it is always running. When the program is triggered the [PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) is always 0;

Even bigger Hints:

> - Useful instructions for assembly language: *Input/Output, Math, branching, stop/halt*
>  - *What is the equivalent mathematical operation to integer overflow?*

Comment: I have an idea about how to solve it, but I somehow doubt it's that easy. First of all, does the BIN column have a purpose at all? Also, does the lack of 1001 in the DUMP column mean that up=0 and down=1?

Comment: Everything within the "************" part is relevant, this chip is a microprocessor, not just memory. It has a 4-bit data cache and a 3-bit instruction cache. and BEGIN BIN DUMP is just the sentence for" Beginning memory dump in Binary format", you could have dumped everything in HEX too...

Comment: I don't think "4-bit data cache and 3-bit instruction cache" makes any sense. Do you mean, rather, that each machine instruction consists of 3 bits of instruction opcode and 4 bits of memory address, or something like that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is correct.

Comment: I  submitted some minor grammar corrections in an edit. You mix present and past tense  in your narrative block. I think it would read better if it was all present tense, but I didn't want to change it.

Comment: The guard was successful by moving only 2 levers. Was the prior state of the levers a valid "code" to open the door? I'm looking to find a state transition that results in a valid code to open the door.

Comment: you know the last three states, and they were invalid.

Comment: I believe @karakuricoder refers to the first opening by the guard. Was the prior attempt successful too?

Comment: You are correct @xhienne. I am asking about the settings immediately prior to the first guard's successful code.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Is encryption used? 2. If so is lever combination encryption/decryption implied in one or more of the the machine instructions or are there explicit machine instructions used for encryption decryption?

Comment: One last one that popped into my head. Does this microprocessor utilize one or more registers? If so, are they hardware registers meaning they are not mapped into the main memory space shown in the print out from the C-SCAN 3000?

Comment: I'm pretty excited about this puzzle. It isn't too complex in its presentation, but is definitely challenging and has a lot going on behind the scenes if I am on the right track! I think I almost have it, but just need to clarify a few things.

Comment: No encryption is used, and there is only one register, the ACC, which is invisible, so it must mean that the data is stored somewhere visible, maybe im giving out too much information.

Comment: Hints added since its been 3 months and no one has given an answer.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***NOTE READ ME***
>
> Don't be scared by the length of the answer. Most of it is explaining microprocessor concepts and can be skipped if you understand that stuff. I just didn't want to assume that other readers had specific knowledge, so I pretty much spell out each step in detail. It made this post a bit long, but understandable by pretty much anyone. If you only care about the solution and not my journey getting there, just skip down to the solution part. It might be worth while reading the "Opcode" sections as I do have some logic used in the solution in those sections as well.

## Initial Logic

When I first saw this about a month and half back, the memory layout immediately made sense to me as I have done some disassembly and microprocessor research for a project in the past. Looking over the C-SCAN 3000 print out, I had some intuitions about the instructions, but decided to do a little internet digging. After many articles and Wikipedia pages I came across 3 concepts that are used pretty heavily in my answer.

Here are the first two:

> [Instruction Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)
>  [Accumulator Registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing))

And the real breakthrough:

> [The Little Man Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer)
>
> More information [here](http://www.povinelli.org/teaching/eece2710/lmc.html) and [here](http://elearning.algonquincollege.com/coursemat/dat2343/lectures.f03/12-LMC.htm)

The first two concepts are important to understand for real world implementation while the breakthrough concept is more conceptual. The breakthrough concept is what will be the basis for the proposed solution. So I have outlined some of the important points below:

## Breakthrough Key Points

> ```
> 1.) A little man is inside of a box. The little man does work 
>     when he gets a "start" signal.
> 2.) A start signal is sent via a button pressed that is external to
>     the box the little man is in.
> 3.) The little man has at his disposal the following:
>     - Unlimited paper and pencils
>     - Mailboxes each capable of holding a single piece of paper
>       at a time
>     - A mailbox counter showing what mailbox the little man he 
>       should look at next
>     - A calculator with some lights on it.
>     - Input and output baskets to...well get input and output 
>       from the outside world.
> 4.) The calculator displays the result of the last operation.
> 5.) The calculator lights illuminate based on the result of the last
>     math operation. They track positive, negative, zero, and 
>     possibly overflow conditions. So performing 2 - 2 would 
>     illuminate the zero light on the calculator while 2 - 3 would
>     illuminate the negative light and so on.
> 6.) When the external button is pressed, the mailbox counter resets
>     to 0.
> ```
>
> There might be some other details so I suggest you give it a read and play with the simulator [here](https://peterhigginson.co.uk/LMC/). What you will notice is our prison gate microprocessor has a very similar structure. It has memory addresses that can store one 7-bit value at a time, an external button that starts execution from memory address 0, input from the gate levers, output to the gate, an accumulator register (ACC) that is capable of holding results from arithmetic calculations. One thing that is not immediately clear is whether ACC keeps its value from a previous run when the gate button is pressed. Until we hear otherwise from the OP, let's assume it is cleared. All we need now is to define what instructions our prison microprocessor supports.

## Instruction Set

> There has already been some talk about instructions in other answers and I think we are all on the right track. The OP has confirmed that there are 5 different instructions used in this program and all of them are the absolute most basic instructions you can get. We can get a list of these basic instructions from the Instruction Sets link above. They are grouped into three categories.
>
> ```
>     Data Instructions:
>         - Load: Load from somewhere. Usually a memory address.
>         - Store: Store somewhere. Usually a memory address.
>         - Input: Getting input from some external hardware.
>         - Output: Sending input to external hardware.
>
>     Arithmetic Instructions:
>         - And: Bit-wise And of two operands.
>         - Or: Bit-wise Or of two operands.
>         - Xor: Bit-wise Xor of two operands.
>         - Add: Adds two operands together.
>         - Subtract: Subtracts one operand from another.
>         - Increment: Specialized version of add that just adds 1 to an 
>           operand.
>         - Decrement: Specialized version of subtract that just 
>           subtracts 1 to an operand.
>
>     Control Flow Instructions:
>         - Unconditional Branch: Branch to another memory address.
>         - Condition Branch: There are many types like branch when 
>           something is equal or when the last math operation resulted in
>           an overflow, etc.
>         - Stop/Halt: Stop the CPU from doing any further execution.
> ```
>
> One thing we have to define are the exact semantics of the above instructions. In normal people speak, we need to define details of how each instruction should work in our prison gate microprocessor. You may be thinking, "It seems pretty obvious what all of these instructions do", but I bring it up because it makes a difference for the Increment and Decrement instructions. I'll explain why this is important later on. So with that, let's start matching our five opcodes with instruction labels!

## First Three Opcodes

> The OP has not officially confirmed this, but @jousle made the assumption that 000 is a Halt instruction and 101 is some kind of Conditional Branch instruction. I think these are reasonable assumptions since they make sense and the OP did not specifically comment on them being wrong as he did with opcode 001 in @jousle's answer. So any memory address where the first 3 bits are 000 is either a Halt instruction or a data slot. So trying to execute a data slot would also halt the program which is good. If you look closely at the memory print out, we can map our third opcode. Each path of the conditional branch terminates, but one path does something slightly different.
>
> ```
>     |BEGIN BIN DUMP |
>     |***************|
>     |0000   001 1111|
>     |0001   010 1101|
>     |0010   001 1101|
>     |0011   001 1100|     Branch on line 0100
>     |0100   101 0111| >---V--->--->---V
>                           | Path 1    |
>     |0101   010 1101| <---<           |
>     |0110   000 0000|                 |
>     |0111   010 1101| <---<---<---<---<
>     |1000   111 0000|    Path 2
>     |1001   000 0000|
> ```
>
> Looking at path 1, we have:
>
> ```
>     010 1101
>     000 0000
> ```
>
> and looking at path 2, we have:
>
> ```
>     010 1101
>     111 0000
>     000 0000
> ```
>
> Path 2 is almost the same, but has one additional instruction. @jousle caught onto this and proposed that it looks like an Output instruction. Basically a signal to the gate to open. The OP has not confirmed this, but I think it is a good guess. With that we have the first 3 opcode matched to their instruction labels. On to the final two opcodes!

## The Final Two

> The final two opcodes gave me a real headache. My initial thoughts were some type of encryption was going on due to the encryption note at the bottom of the C-SCAN 3000 print out. The OP confirmed that was not the case. My next realization was that the remaining two opcodes can not be Control Flow instructions. If they were the first 4 instructions could possibly terminate the program without ever doing anything useful and definitely without opening the gate. We can also weed out Input as a possibility pretty quick because why would you get input more than once? In addition there looks to be an operand associated with both opcodes where Input and Output do not need any operands as we saw with the 111 opcode at memory address 1000.
>
> Load can also be weeded out as loading into the ACC does not make a lot of sense. In the case of opcode 001 why would you load something and then immediately overwrite it with another Load? In the case of 010 why would you load something and terminate the program without doing anything with the loaded value? Both are illogical actions so we can toss the Load instruction out. This leaves us with the following instructions to choose from: Add, Subtract, Increment, Decrement, and Store. We can eliminate specific combinations of instructions.
>
> For example having one instruction be addition and the other be subtraction would not give you any change in output between runs of the program given the same lever positions as input. We know this can't be the case since the unlucky prisoner from our story would have gotten through the gate when he pressed the button right after the guard using the same lever positions. We can also weed out one of them being an Increment instruction and the other a Decrement instruction. If that were the case, the levers' positions would be irrelevant. One could just smash the button every two seconds until the gate opened up. In the end the reduced list of instruction combinations that actually do something logical is:
>
> ```
>     001      | 010
>
>     --------------------
>  1. Add      | Store
>  2. Add      | Increment
>  3. Add      | Decrement
>  4. Subtract | Increment
>  5. Subtract | Decrement
> ```
>
> Let's see which of these combinations of instructions actually hold up. In the following, I am going to use decimal numbers for memory addresses and data while the instructions will use 3 character abbreviations just to be able to understand things a little better instead of looking a 010100100101....

## Opcode Set 1

> I first tried combination #1. It looked very promising because having the Store instruction let's us see the value of ACC which makes it easier to reverse execute the program and find the mystery branch condition. Another benefit of this combination is the fact that the value in ACC gets doubled after finishing lines 0001 and 0010:
>
> ```
>     |BEGIN BIN DUMP |
>     |***************|
>     |0000   ADD 0015|
>     |0001   STO 0013|----> These two instructions perform the doubling.
>     |0002   ADD 0013|----> They store X from ACC then add the stored X
>     |0003   ADD 0012|      to itself. So ACC = X + X.
>     |0004   B?? 0007|
> ```
>
> The cool thing about this is it gives us a way fail this combination! Any time you double a number regardless of whether the value before the doubling is odd or even, the end result will always be even. If we ever see an odd number in ACC when we reach line 0011 during our reverse execution, this combination of instructions becomes invalid. With that in mind, I started working backwards from the unlucky prisoner's last attempt.
>
> ```
>     Instruction Descriptions
>     ADD: Add value stored at memory address represented by the
>          operand to ACC value and store in ACC.
>     B??: Branch on some condition.
>     OUT: Output signal to open the gate.
>     HLT: halt execution.
>     STO: Store ACC value at memory location represented by operand.
>
>     Prisoner Attempt: 3
>     Levers: Up,Down,Down,Up = 0110 = 6
>     MEM[0013]: 1110 = 14
>
>     |BEGIN BIN DUMP |
>     |***************|
>     |0000   ADD 0015|
>     |0001   STO 0013|
>     |0002   ADD 0013|
>     |0003   ADD 0012|
>     |0004   B?? 0007|
>     |0005   STO 0013|
>     |0006   HLT     |
>     |0007   STO 0013|
>     |0008   OUT     |
>     |0009   HLT     |
>     |0010   000 0000|
>     |0011   000 0000|
>     |0012   000   13| <- Data Value 13
>     |0013   000   14| <- Data Value 14
>     |0014   000 0000|
>     |0015   000 0110|
>     |***************|
>
>
>
>     Reverse Execute MEM[0005]: STO MEM[0013]
>         ACC = MEM[0013] = 14
>         ACC = 14
>
>     ACC: 14
>     Reverse Execute MEM[0004]: B?? MEM[0007]
>         - We know the branch failed and just came from the failed 
>           leg of it. We can move on to the next instruction and
>           reverse execute it.
>
>     ACC: 14
>     Reverse Execute MEM[0003]: ADD MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC - MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC - 13
>         ACC = 14 - 13
>         ACC = 1
> ```
>
> Right away our alarm goes off because we know 1 is odd. It is impossible to find a whole number that when doubled gives us 1, so reverse executing the next two steps is impossible. That means this instruction combination is not valid.

## Opcode Set 2

> Combination #2 utilizes the Increment instruction, so this is a good place to explain why I introduced this nit pick detail about semantics of the Increment and Decrement instructions above. Let's look at Increment as the same logic applies to Decrement. One way of implementing the Increment instruction on a memory address is having the CPU load the value at the target memory address into ACC, adding 1 to it, and then storing it back into memory again. You can think of it as a group execution consisting of a Load, Add, and Store instructions like this:
>
> ```
>     Load X: Load the value at memory address X into the ACC.
>     Add 1: Increment the ACC by 1.
>     Store X: Store the ACC value at memory address X.
> ```
>
> The problem may not be immediately obvious until you try to work backwards. You quickly see that you can't determine what was in the ACC register before the "Load X" instruction without some other context prior to the Load. Essentially the Load instruction overwrote the data in ACC. There are ways around this, but the program we were given is not designed in a way that we can determine what ACC was before it was used to increment something. We would be lucky if we had a second register to do increments in, but the OP confirmed to my earlier question that this microprocessor has a single accumulator register and no others.
>
> A second way the Increment instruction could work is by adding 1 "in memory". This would not require the use of the ACC, but would require the microprocessor design to support "in memory" semantics for the Increment and Decrement instruction. The ACC value would be preserved for us to know what it is and we could then reverse execute the program. I'll spoil the surprise now. Without this assumption, there seems to be no solution to the puzzle without adding complex instructions to our initial list defined above. Increment and Decrement are already starting to get into the realm of complex instructions, but they are sometimes found in the simplest of microprocessors. If I have taken us down some dark and dangerous path of reasoning, the OP will most definitely let us know in a comment and clarify the muddy water I have made. Until that happens, let's use this "in memory" assumption and find a working solution to the puzzle!
>
> So without further ado, here is the solution!

## Finally A Solution

> Combination #1 is the solution to the puzzle using the assumptions above. I won't go into the detail of the other combinations, but try them yourself and you will see there is no clean branch condition that can be used to solve the puzzle. Combination #1 assigns the Add instruction to 001 and Increment instruction to 010 and produces a solution that generates a branch condition for the attempt to open the gate made by the guard, but no branch condition on all of the unlucky prisoner's attempts! Let's reverse execute the program and see what the branch condition is!
>
> ```
>     Instruction Descriptions
>     ADD: Add value stored at memory address represented by the operand to ACC value and store in ACC.
>     B??: Branch on some condition.
>     OUT: Output signal to open the gate.
>     HLT: halt execution.
>     INC: Increment the value at the memory address represented by the operand by 1.
>
>     Levers: Down,Up, Down,Down = 1011 = 11
>
>     |BEGIN BIN DUMP |
>     |***************|
>     |0000   ADD 0015|
>     |0001   INC 0013|
>     |0002   ADD 0013|
>     |0003   ADD 0012|
>     |0004   B?? 0007|
>     |0005   INC 0013|
>     |0006   HLT     |
>     |0007   INC 0013|
>     |0008   OUT     |
>     |0009   HLT     |
>     |0010   000 0000|
>     |0011   000 0000|
>     |0012   000   13| <- Non Changing Data Value 13
>     |0013   000   14| <- Counter value 14
>     |0014   000 0000|
>     |0015   000 0110|
>     |***************|
> ```
>
> Let's assume that when the button is pressed, the program counter and the ACC register are both reset to 0. The only persistent information is what we see in memory. If we focus on the memory and instructions for a second, we can notice that there are two data items that change between runs that are interesting to us. The first is the lever input at memory address 15. We obviously use that. The second is the counter value at memory address 13. It counts up by 2 each time the program is run regardless of whether the gate was opened or not. That means to re-create the prisoner's 3rd attempt we need to just subtract 2 from the counter at MEM[0013] and re-run the program. Doing that we get the following outcome:
>
> ```
>     Prisoner Attempt: 3
>     Lever Positions: 0110 = 6
>     MEM[0013]: 1100 = 12
>
>     ACC: 0
>     Execute MEM[0000]: ADD MEM[0015]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0015]
>         ACC = ACC + 6
>         ACC = 0 + 6
>         ACC = 6
>
>     ACC: 6
>     Execute MEM[0001]: Increment MEM[0013]
>         MEM[0013] = 12
>         INC MEM[0013]
>         MEM[0013] = 13
>
>     ACC: 6
>     Execute MEM[0002]: ADD MEM[0013]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0013]
>         ACC = ACC + 13
>         ACC = 6 + 13
>         ACC = 3
> ```
>
> Now you may be wondering why ACC is 3 and not 19? Since we can only store 4 bits of data, when we reach 15 or 1111 everything wraps around back to 0 and counts from there. This is [Modulus Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) where the modulus is 16. Depending on the microprocessor, this wrap around, or overflow as it is also known, might be a condition that is recorded. Since we have more math operations before our branch, this particular overflow is not important to us as it only applies to the last math operation.
>
> ```
>     ACC: 3
>     Execute MEM[0003]: ADD MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC + 13
>         ACC = 3 + 13
>         ACC = 0
> ```
>
> Here we have another overflow condition, but this time it is right before our branch. So we can't say for certain until we test the other attempts, but one condition to open the gate might be using lever positions that do not trigger an overflow on the last addition. The next instruction is the branch which we pass through since we know the gate did not open. The last instruction before the halt takes our counter back up to 14.
>
> We have to go back through all of the prisoner's attempts and the guard's attempts to see if all of the prisoner's attempts produce overflow while the guard's does not. If so then that is one possible solution. Since I have already done this and the process is pretty much the same as the above, I will only do the guard's attempt. You can verify, but the prisoner's attempts all produce overflow conditions. For the guard's attempt, we need to roll back 4 attempts, putting our counter at MEM[0013] to 6.
>
> ```
>     Guard Attempt
>     Lever Positions: 1011 = 11
>     MEM[0013]: 0110 = 6
>
>     ACC: 0
>     Execute MEM[0000]: ADD MEM[0015]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0015]
>         ACC = ACC + 11
>         ACC = 0 + 11
>         ACC = 11
>
>     ACC: 11
>     Execute MEM[0001]: Increment MEM[0013]
>         MEM[0013] = 6
>         INC MEM[0013]
>         MEM[0013] = 7
>
>     ACC: 11
>     Execute MEM[0002]: ADD MEM[0013]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0013]
>         ACC = ACC + 7
>         ACC = 11 + 7
>         ACC = 2
>
>     ACC: 2
>     Execute MEM[0003]: ADD MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC + 13
>         ACC = 2 + 13
>         ACC = 15
> ```
>
> Lucky us! No overflow! So one possible solution is to produce no overflow. Using that as the criteria let's see what lever positions our protagonist need to produce in order to escape.
>
> ```
>     Protagonist Attempt
>     Lever Positions: ???? = X
>     MEM[0013]: 1110 = 14
>
>     ACC: 0
>     Execute MEM[0000]: ADD MEM[0015]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0015]
>         ACC = ACC + X
>         ACC = 0 + X
>         ACC = X
>
>     ACC: X
>     Execute MEM[0001]: Increment MEM[0013]
>         MEM[0013] = 14
>         INC MEM[0013]
>         MEM[0013] = 15
>
>     ACC: X
>     Execute MEM[0002]: ADD MEM[0013]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0013]
>         ACC = ACC + 15
>         ACC = X + 15
>         ACC = X + 15
>
>     ACC: 2
>     Execute MEM[0003]: ADD MEM[0012]
>         ACC = ACC + MEM[0012]
>         ACC = (X + 15) + 13
> ```
>
> Some simple arithmetic shows us that lever combination 0011 or Up, Up, Down, Down will not cause an overflow and get our guy through. His family can also get through if we follow a very specific pattern:
>
> ```
>     (X + 1) + 13 -> X = 0001 = 1
>     (X + 3) + 13 -> X = 1111 = 15
>     (X + 5) + 13 -> X = 1101 = 13
> ```
>
> All you need to do to get the next lever position is subtract two from the previous combination represented in numerical form.

## Solution 2?

> The thought may have crossed your mind in the last section that our protagonist could have used another set of lever positions to escape and you would be correct! In fact every new attempt has two possible combination that open the gate. So the protagonist and his family could use 0010, 0000, 1110, 1100 to open the gate. It is probably the solution, but there could be another answer. When looking closely at the C-SCAN 3000 print out and the guard's attempt to open the gate, I noticed something. The guard produced a final value in ACC of 1111 before the branch happened. When I was analyzing the C-SCAN 3000 print out, I was focused on the lower section as it seemed to provide no value to the problem:
>
> ```
>     |***************|
>     |ACC &%#$  ERROR|
>     |ENCRYPTED VALUE|
>     |               |
>     |1111 EXT.      |
>     |               |
>     |FURTHER DEBUG. |
>     |UPGRADE TO C-  |
>     |SCAN 4000+     |
>     |               |
>     |EOF            |
>     -----------------
> ```
>
> I originally focused on the encrypted value part, but the OP told me there was no encryption. I dismissed the whole bottom section, but later realized that the "1111 EXT." part may have a meaning. It could be 1111 Extension or could it be 1111 Exit! Does it mean you have to get ACC to equal 1111 to get the exit to open? If that is true, the solution 1 lever positions produce an ACC value of 1111 and we no longer have multiple lever positions opening the gate ever. Usually this would be done with a compare instruction against some some memory address holding the value 1111, but there could be a custom instruction specific to this microprocessor that checks the ACC for the value 1111. The OP would have to weigh in an address some of these assumptions before we can say for sure.

So there it is! Lever positions that will allow our guy to escape to the next area with his family! I had a lot of fun doing this and look forward to seeing what happens to our protagonist, who needs a cool name btw ;)

Comment: This is probably one of my favorite puzzles I have come across here. The story and puzzle itself are simple, but underneath it is pretty tough problem to solve. I have had the best time trying to solve it! May not be the right answer, but I won't give up until someone gets it!

Comment: Congrats for the quality of your answer! It deserves ten times more votes.

Comment: @xhienne Thanks! I had a lot of fun doing this puzzle. I kind of wish there was some others like it. Might even make my own ;)

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

**Memory:**

Data is located in 1100, 1101, and 1111.  Since 1111 holds 0110, which corresponds to the last position of the levers (Up Down Down Up), it could be that it stores the state of the levers when the button is pushed.

**Program Execution:**

I believe pushing the button starts the program, and the instruction 000 stops it.  ACC I think holds the state of the levers at the time the button is pushed (up = 0 and down = 1).

**Instructions:**

001 is probably a store operation. (stores the contents of ACC in the memory location given).

010 also takes memory addresses as arguments. It looks like a math operation by process of elimination.

101 looks like a conditional branch operation that takes a line number as it's argument (jumps to 0111).  It's curious though because line 0111 and 0101 are the same, so it begs the question why not put this instruction before the branch and avoid the duplicate.  Perhaps it's because the branch relies on the result of the previous instruction.

000 probably stops the program.

111 probably opens the door.  Therefore, in order to open the door, we need to trigger the branch operation to avoid the 000 instruction at line 0110.

Comment: You're very close! Regarding the 001 instruction, here's something: Why would the program store the values to 1111 and then never use them again? Could it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

**Incomplete Solution**

---

By painstakingly converting the Binary Dump into Hexadecimal, I have gained a few insights:

1. The first column is counting from 0 to 15 in binary. This most likely represents the program counter(PC).
2. The levers only correspond to the memory when Down corresponds to 1 and Up corresponds to 0 and when they are read in reverse order. Ex: DUDD becomes 1101.
3. The levers could also correspond to the PC, however it seems unlikely since a processor usually keeps track of the PC internally.
4. The only place where the second lever state shows up in memory is the last location.

**My Notes**

> PC, INST, MEM
>   ------------------------- t = 0s 
>   0000   001 1111 | 0, 1, F  
>   0001   010 1101 | 1, 2, D  
>   0010   001 1101 | 2, 1, D  
>   0011   001 1100 | 3, 1, C  
>   ------------------------- t = 1s 
>   0100   101 0111 | 4, 5, 7  
>   0101   010 1101 | 5, 2, D  
>   0110   000 0000 | 6, 0, 0  
>   0111   010 1101 | 7, 2, D  
>   ------------------------- t = 2s 
>   1000   111 0000 | 8, 7, 0  
>   1001   000 0000 | 9, 0, 0  
>   1010   000 0000 | A, 0, 0  
>   1011   000 0000 | B, 0, 0  
>   ------------------------- t = 3s 
>   1100   000 1101 | C, 0, D  
>   1101   000 1110 | D, 0, E  
>   1110   000 0000 | E, 0, 0  
>   1111   000 0110 | F, 0, 6  
>   Note: I divided the dump into four sections of four lines since the C-Scan report said that the processor ran at 4 cycles per second

---

Until I can work on this again, hopefully this helps someone, the answer definitely lies in figuring out what the instructions do.

Answer (score 1):

**Still Incomplete**

Adding to Areeb's answer:

1. If the last state of the levers corresponds to the last memory state
   we must assume that pressing the red button with an invalid lever
   configuration does nothing in the IC other than add 1 program
   control (PC) line in the dump. Since the anxious person (AP) presses
   the button twice w/o moving the levers, then moves three levers and
   presses the button (w/o the door opening), we would think that there
   would be three PC lines where nothing happened, but that the memory
   should reflect the state of the levers. (I must be wrong about this
   as it doesn't in lines 13, 14, but does on 15).
2. We also assume that when a valid lever position is indicated, the
   processor operates at 4 instructions/second.  Keep in mind that it
   took 2 seconds for the door to open.
3. In light of #1, the only place the MEM could reflect the guard
   moving two levers before pushing the button is at lines 4,5.
4. Counting off 2 seconds from there has the door opening on line 12.

Here's my take on what each line could mean:

> PC  INST MEM     COMMENT
>   0  0000 001 1111 | Unknown instruction
>   1  0001 010 1101 | Unknown instruction.  Used when Guard opens door on line 5
>   2  0010 001 1101 | Unknown instruction
>   3  0011 001 1100 | Unknown instruction
>   4  0100 101 0111 | Last state of levers before Guard moves them. (Inst. only seen once)
>   ------------------------- t = 0s
>   5  0101 010 1101 | Guard moves 2 levers (2nd and 4th)
>                                 and pushes button and waits 2 seconds for door to open
>   6  0110 000 0000 | Unknown wait time
>   7  0111 010 1101 | Unknown instruction (repeat of line 5)
>   8  1000 111 0000 | Unknown instruction (maybe 'success')
>   ------------------------- t = 1s
>    9 1001 000 0000 | Unknown wait time
>   10 1010 000 0000 | Unknown wait time
>   11 1011 000 0000 | Unknown wait time
>   12 1100 000 1101 | Door opens (closes automatically), MEM reflects levers
>   ------------------------- nothing happening while AP approaches levers
>   13 1101 000 1110 | AP pushed button 1st time (Hm, the MEM should be 1101)
>   14 1110 000 0000 | AP pushed button 2nd time (should still be 1101)
>   15 1111 000 0110 | AP moved 3 levers and pushed button 3rd time

There are holes in this theory, but if it's correct then something about line 5 tells us how the door can be opened.  Maybe a correlation of the PC and the MEM, say absolute value of MEM minus the PC, so on line five the result would be 8, b1000. This would mean the IC is always looking for the result to be 8.  Since this is a 4-bit processor we must assume the next line number rolls over to zero - b0000.  Therefore the next MEM value should be b1000 corresponding to a lever position of Up Up Up Down.

There must be flaws in my thinking, though as, carrying this out for the next two door openings, leads to a repeating cycle of MEM values alternating between b0000 and b1000 until someone presses the button with a wrong lever position.

Not sure what the "ACC &%#$  ERROR ENCRYPTED VALUE  1111 EXT." is on the printout; a monkey-wrench I'm certain!   Maybe somebody can take my thoughts and find the real answer.